# How to access Devise_token_auth access token of omniauth provider?

Tags: angularjs, api, devise, omniauth, access-token

How do I access the access token of the omniauth provider that should be sent back after successful authentication with the devise_token_auth gem and ng-token-auth with angular? I'd like to store this token to make future requests to the omniauth provider for updating information. The omniauth provider specifically is Strava. I see that devise_token_auth is creating its own access tokens, but those aren't for accessing Strava. Also I have no idea even where devise token auth pulls in the information from Strava even after reading through the gem's code. Seems like this should be a pretty simple thing, I can't be the only one who wants this information returned. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We have been able to figure this out with a lot of experimentation. `@resouce` does return nil for us too, but we did find the access-token and all the other information returned from the omniauth provider, located in `request.env['omniauth.auth']`, located in the `redirect_callbacks` action of the `OmniAuthCallbacks` controller. We also needed to set up

`mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'registrations'}`

in `routes.rb`, and create the custom controller which we named RegistrationsController.

So our block looked like this

```
class RegistrationsController < DeviseTokenAuth::OmniauthCallbacksController

    def redirect_callbacks
        super
        puts "REDIRECT:"
        puts request.env['omniauth.params']
        puts "AUTH INFO"
        puts request.env['omniauth.auth'].credentials['token']
        puts "REDIRECT END"
        # create the user_strava_key and save it.
        @strava_token = request.env['omniauth.auth'].credentials['token']
        UserStravaKey.create(key_secret: @strava_token)
    end

end
```